# Copy resources with maven without change previous config

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I work on a spring boot project and I have this config in effective pom.xml :

```
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>/home/farid/Travaux/ng-with-boot/src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/application*.yml</include>
          <include>**/application*.yaml</include>
          <include>**/application*.properties</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>/home/farid/Travaux/ng-with-boot/src/main/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/application*.yml</exclude>
          <exclude>**/application*.yaml</exclude>
          <exclude>**/application*.properties</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
```

I just want to add another conf to copy a front end app to the static folder so I did this :

```
       <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/frontend/dist</directory>
                <targetPath>static</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

But, now, the previous config is not kept.

How can I copy my new files without erase the spring boot config?

Comment: Did you add your new resource to the contents of your resources tag?

Comment: What do you mean by "add new resource to the contents of your resources tag"? I have files in "src/main/frontend/dist" and the build add these files in "static" folder